# What's the correct way to safely splice into a wire meant for mains voltage

Tags: ac, relay, safety

I want to use a relay to control some 230VAC equipment, by doing so i want to toggle the live wire.

Is there a standard/safe method to do this in terms of the components to use, or is it a matter of cutting into the outer sleeve, then cutting the live wire, and inserting them into some screw in terminals like [this](https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/docs/stock/connectors/2-54mm-screwterminal.jpg) which then connect to the relay?

Edit: Of course the wire will be *not live* when I'm working on it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have added clarification. I'd not go to the internet to ask how to work on live wire when it's live. I can understand how you came to that conclusion though - I mean the live wire of a three pin plug, not a wire that is live.

Comment: Do you have a choice of the relay? You can get them with 4 mm terminals which accept spade connectors. The spade connector (with appropriate insulation) is easily crimped onto the wire with the correct tool.

Comment: I misinterpreted the question, hence my comment (I know companies that specialize in working on live, HV circuits with special tools and techniques, hence it's not impossible, and I was fearing the worst).

Comment: @Orbitronics You would be distressed at some of the questions that get asked here...

Comment: @JorenVaes Sorry friend, I've had one bad experience of a guy who told me I shouldn't even consider designing a DAC because i couldn't figure out which IC to use for the SPDIF to I2S conversion, and it shot my confidence, so I came to a negative conclusion with your comment. 

I didn't understand until Andrew asked that you may have thought I was handling live wire like an idiot - in which case I'm sorry for the confusion. I will do the work when everything is totally disconnected. I just wanted to know if my idea as written above is in the right direction.

Comment: @Orbitronics perhaps editing the title to something like "splice a wire meant for mains voltages" such that there is no room for misinterpretation?
And no worries, I can totally understand your response. It's just that some of the people ask questions like that and genuinly mean *working while circuits are live*.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I can imagine, though browsing this site gives me the feeling there's a lot of smart people here too. 

At the moment I have a very decent single coil latching relay, as I'm doing an energy conscious design, it's the EC2-5SNU (THT). Having said that the design is from scratch so I can switch it up so i'll have a look at your recommendation. I was just getting itchy because the NC/COM/NO pins are 0.1" pitch, so i wondered if i should cover them in epoxy/hot glue to stop potential shorts etc.

Comment: @JorenVaes Thanks, I went ahead with the edit. I genuinely wonder how more people haven't died from touching the live wire.

Comment: @Orbitronics Is the load purely resistive, or is it something like a transformer which is being switched? If the latter, you might want to consider an RC snubber across the relay contacts to make them last longer.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's a dual SPDT relay at the moment, so I might go ahead and have one rail toggle some LEDs, and the other for the design's main purpose, to toggle 40W speakers. 

I'm still considering various relays, but the one's i currently have are single coil latching, so I believe i need to use a couple of snubber diodes like this: https://goo.gl/YPFHAx since the current switches direction for the setting/resetting. I haven't considered an RC snubber.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this type of wiring would be using crimp connections such as spade lugs or quick-connect lugs, making sure everything uses the male counterpart.

They come in various shapes and sizes. For mains, I would suggest getting the shielded type. (Picture shows unshielded version so it's clearer what type I'm talking about) [image]

You need the right type of tool to crimp these in.

Comment: Thanks, then I think I need to purchase these: https://goo.gl/Cwf67e

And thanks to you and Andrew I learnt that i should use spade connectors in general.

If I wanted to use the existing THT relay I have, as shown here: https://goo.gl/UsW8xu

Would it be unsafe to do the following: https://goo.gl/3kz5mj

Note the small red lines I added. 

I'm sure if i did that, it'd be much safer if i crimped the wire before placing them in the screw-in terminal.

Comment: You *should* get these connectors with insulation over the spade part as well, but if you can't you can heatshrink over the top.  You can also tether the wires to prevent a single broken connection from contacting anything else, whether that's dodgy crimping, a snapped-off pin or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Safely and legally are not necessarily the same thing.

A lot depends on where you plan on splicing. If this is intended for splicing into the mains wiring of a facility or home the requirements will be significantly different to say splicing into the cheapo zipper cable that's attached to your table lamp. Further, depending on where you live, codes may differ.

The crimped spade connectors indicated in Joren's answer are probably the handiest to work with, but do suffer from installation issues if you are not using the right tools or the right kinds and diameter of wires. I have seen the wire come out of those too many times.

If it's for splicing into single core mains cable, push in connectors are acceptable and available in some regions, "[wire nuts](https://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA9KK3G92021&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwordsCAMKPL-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwordsCAMKPL-PC-_-pla-_-HI%20-%20Wire%20%26%20Cable%20Connectors%20%26%20Insulation-_-9SIA9KK3G92021&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIr4b7x-vU1gIVQWt-Ch2y2wHTEAQYASABEgJwnfD_BwE)" are widely used in North America, but ultimately, you can't beat screw down connectors.

A bigger issue though is enclosing all that, possibly in a grounded "box", and including sufficient strain relief and or clamping to ensure no tension or twisting forces on the cable can be transferred to your connection.